# Vim: My plugins and color schemes won't work?

Tags: vim, plugins

I was trying to play around with my vimrc file and discovered plugins (specifically one that should allow me to scroll through color schemes) however it seems that the plugins are not working.  What I mean by this is that the 'ScrollColors.vim' file should create a :SCROLL command to scroll through the colorschemes, but when I try that in vim it says "E492: Not an editor command: SCROLL".  Also, I tried adding a line ":Colorscheme Mustang" to my vimrc file (mustang is a colorscheme file in the colors directory) but when I start vim it says "E185: Cannot find color scheme Mustang"

Any help would be appreciated!

Also, if this helps, this is my vim directory:

```
SDs-macbook:MacVim-ppc-i386-10_5-7_3-53 Simona$ ls
MacVim.app      README.txt      colors  mvim    plugin
```

And my plugin directory:

```
SDs-macbook:plugin Simona$ ls
ScrollColors.vim    color_sample_pack.vim   mimicpak.vim
```

Comment: They are case-sensitive. In your vimrc, you would add `colorscheme mustang` without the preceding `:`

Comment: The name of the directory should be `.vim`, in your user's home directory. and use pathogen, do not ever install plugins without pathogen. vim is a POS if you don't use a plugin manager. you will also need to restart vim between plugin installs. close question plz.

Comment: @AndyRay Pathogen is not a tiny bit a plugin manager, it is runtimepath manager: it is not able to install, update or remove plugins. Plugin managers are things like [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle) and [vim-addon-manager](https://github.com/MarcWeber/vim-addon-manager).

Comment: tomato tomato. it makes installing / removing plugins super easy. i'm calling it a plugin manager.

Answer (score 0):

Commands in Vim are case-sensitive; built-in commands like `:colorscheme` are lowercase, custom commands defined by plugins must start with an uppercase letter, but rarely are all-caps, because that is hard to type. The command may be `:Scroll` instead.

You can use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to complete commands (e.g. `:S<Tab>`), and use `:command` to list all defined commands. (But reading the plugin's help is usually easier.)